# XML::Simple & accessing complex structures

Tags: xml, arrays, perl, hash, xml-parsing

I'm having an issue accessing some nested data in an XML response using Perl/XML::Simple.  An extract of the printed XML reply looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:SelectCmDeviceResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/">
<SelectCmDeviceResult xsi:type="ns1:SelectCmDeviceResult">
<TotalDevicesFound xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">3</TotalDevicesFound>
<CmNodes soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CmNode[3]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<item xsi:type="ns1:CmNode">
<ReturnCode xsi:type="ns1:RisReturnCode">NotFound</ReturnCode>
<Name xsi:type="xsd:string">10.186.78.4</Name>
<NoChange xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</NoChange>
<CmDevices soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CmDevice[0]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array"/>
</item>
<item xsi:type="ns1:CmNode">
<ReturnCode xsi:type="ns1:RisReturnCode">Ok</ReturnCode>
<Name xsi:type="xsd:string">10.186.78.68</Name>
<NoChange xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</NoChange>
<CmDevices soapenc:arrayType="ns1:CmDevice[2]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
<item xsi:type="ns1:CmDevice">
<Name xsi:type="xsd:string">SEPD0574CF73FC0</Name>
<IpAddress xsi:type="xsd:string">10.186.79.41</IpAddress>
<DirNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">51251001-Registered,51251004-Registered,51251002-Registered</DirNumber>
<Class xsi:type="ns1:DeviceClass">Phone</Class>
<Model xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">404</Model>
<Product xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">303</Product>
<BoxProduct xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">0</BoxProduct>
```

Here is the code, which should parse the response and return the IpAddress values of the returned devices:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use LWP;
use SOAP::Lite;

my $cucmip = "10.1.10.1";
my $axl_port = "8443";
my $user = "admin";
my $password = "password";
my $axltoolkit = "http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/action/#RisPort#SelectCmDevice";

sub getDevIp {
    my $message = "<?xml POST message>

    my $url="https://$cucmip:$axl_port/realtimeservice/services/RisPort?wsdl";
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $header = new HTTP::Headers (
    'Content-Type' => 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction' => 'http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/action/#RisPort#SelectCmDevice',
    );
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url, $header, $message);
    $req->authorization_basic($user,$password);
    my $response = $ua->request($req);
    my $xs = new XML::Simple(KeyAttr=>[]);
    my $data = $xs->XMLin($response->content);
    print $data->{'soapenv:Body'}->{'ns1:SelectCmDeviceResponse'}->{'SelectCmDeviceResult'}->{'CmNodes'}->{'item'}->[0]->{'CmDevices'}->{'item'}->[0]->{'IpAddress'}->{'content'};
}

getDevIp();
```

Comment: Do you seriously expect anyone to scroll back and forth horizontally to understand this? Don't use `XML::Simple` if your data structure is too complicated.

Comment: I did scroll a bit and recognized the data you are trying to access in your example does not exist. Autovivification will create an `undef` value when accessing the (non existant) key. Do you `use strict;` and `use warnings;`?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - Messy, I do agree but I figured it would be better than mistakenly changing a part of the data that might be important to someone that wanted to help.

Comment: @mugenkenichi - thanks for taking the time to look.  use strict; just tells me that I'm using an uninitialized value once I get to the second item array, which is why I'm posting here.  I'm obviously not reading the response correctly.  Perhaps you could offer a solution or point out where I may be misreading it.  To me, it looks like I'm drilling down the structure in the same way that it's returned.

Comment: The solution is to post the actual XML instead of insisting on we make heads or tails out of this data structure.

Comment: @MartinSloan: Then post your actual code please and the xml. Like this we are unable to figure out what your problem is. The warning about the uninitialized value is the result of what I said earlier.

Comment: I modified the post to include the original XML response (a portion of it) and more of the code that I'm using.  Thanks.

Comment: And you are still accessing the very same data that does not exist. If this is the problem fix it by checking your hash structure with `Data::Dumper` as you did. If it is not the actual problem you have to be more specific and boil it down to a minimal version. You will not get debugging of your code here.

Comment: @mugenkenichi:Yep, that's because I haven't changed anything since the first post.  I'm kinda stuck, and thought I could find some help here.  I certainly don't expect you to debug my code, but it sounds like you know a bit about what data I'm trying to access that isn't there but you don't feel inclined to point it out.  I am no Perl expert by any stretch so if you feel my request isn't worthy of your expertise, oh well.  I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what you have.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'soapenv:Body' => {
        'ns1:SelectCmDeviceResponse' => {
            'SelectCmDeviceResult' => {
                'CmNodes' => {
                    'item' => [
                        {
                            'xsi:type'  => 'ns1:CmNode',
                            'CmDevices' => {
                                'soapenc:arrayType' => 'ns1:CmDevice[0]',
                                'xsi:type'          => 'soapenc:Array'
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    # plus some more items with DIFFERENT structure
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

You are trying to access with

```
$data->{'soapenv:Body'}
    ->{'ns1:SelectCmDeviceResponse'}
        ->{'SelectCmDeviceResult'}
            ->{'CmNodes'}
                ->{'item'}->[0]                # you probably want ->[1] here! (wild guess)
                    ->{'CmDevices'}
                        ->{'item'}->[0]        # this data does not exist
                            ->{'IpAddress'}    # and this does not exist
                                ->{'content'}; # and this
```

The values that do not exist are created by perl on first access (this is called autovivification) and initialized `undef`.

That is the reason for your warning.

Comment: And I guess the question was downvoted because you seem too lazy to read the comments below your question and think about them for more that 10 seconds.

Comment: @mugenenkenichi - Nah, you're wrong. It was down voted pretty much immediately and most likely because of the huge Dumper response that I posted which was hard to read, but I did explain that I thought it would be better to include more details than leave them out (I also complied to post the XML which you requested). And about being lazy, super classy. You know me very well then. I do appreciate the latest reply with some details on where I might be going wrong.  Once I really get the hang of this, I'll be sure to be a bit easier on the other lazy folks out there if I'm able to contribute.

Comment: When asking questions it is usually expected to post working code examples (working for anyone) that show your problem. And if necessary complete (!) input and expected output. That makes it easier for the other lazy folks to answer your question. Anyway.. I did not mean to be rude but I get slightly aggressive traversing other peoples hashes ;)

Comment: I'll try to make my requests clearer in the future.  This one was tough since I had a load of data but one very specific issue.  The code does work, except for assigning the value of the hash for IpAddress.  I have a dozen or more scripts that do roughly the same thing correctly, but this hash is a tough one.  Thanks again for the details above.  I haven't had a chance to get back into this one, but will let you know if it works.

Comment: @mugenenkenichi - So it was definitely the [1] instead of [0] that was tripping me up, thanks for pointing that out.  I thought that the elements always began at [0].  Do you have any recommended reading to better understand paring xml hash structures?

Comment: They begin at 0 but your `Data::Dumper` dump showed that your data was at the seconde element. All I can recommend are the excelent perl tutorials and docs at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SOAP::Deserializer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SOAP%3a%3aDeserializer). I cannot try it because I don't have access to the XML document you are parsing. It returns a [SOAP::SOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SOAP%3a%3aSOM) object.

> `valueof(node)`

```
    $res = $som->valueof('[1]');
```

> When the `SOAP::SOM` object has matched a path internally with the match method, this method allows retrieval of the data within any of the matched nodes. The data comes back as native Perl data, not a class instance (see dataof). In a scalar context, this method returns just the first element from a matched node set. In an <del>array</del> list context, all elements are returned. Assuming that the earlier call happens after the earlier call to match, it retrieves the result entity from the method response that is contained in $som, as this is the first child element in a method-response tag.